# How do I replace the last character in a string with VB6?

Tags: string, vb6

How do I replace the last character in a string with VB6? I've got the syntax

```
Replace$(expression, find, replacewith[, start[, count[, compare]]])
```

but I can't seem to find the right use of it. I've got something like

```
iLength = Len(sBuild)
sBuild = Replace(sBuild, "^", "ú", iLength, 1)
```

This isn't working but I can't seem to find any examples online.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

`sBuild = Left$(sBuild, iLength - 1) & "ú"`

Comment: Brilliant. I was so stuck on replace I forgot about that method. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Another method is to use the Mid() keyword:

```
Mid$(sBuild, Len(sBuild), 1) = "ú"
```

This also has the advantage of not doing string concatenation/memory reallocation.

Comment: Far preferable to the other answer.  But use the $ variation of this.  Even though it is the same (here) this helps avoid the bad habit of using Variant *functions*.

Comment: I've adjusted the keyword name and fixed the offset :p

Comment: This is the proper way; much more efficient. This should be the selected answer.